# Linux access point (airmon-ng/airmon-ng) not working

Tags: linux, nat, access-point, airmon-ng

Background:  I am trying to set up an access point on Linux.  The ultimate aim is to run SSLStrip (for an exercise) so I need to be able to do something like this, to redirect port 80 traffic through port 10000, on which SSLStrip listens.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10000
```

Using Linux - Kali2, 64bit.  Machine has internet access via eth0.

---

This is how I am setting up the access point:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0 6
modprobe tun

ifconfig wlan0mon down
iwconfig wlan0mon mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0mon up

airbase-ng -e "MyAccessPoint" -c 6 wlan0mon &

ifconfig "at0" up
ifconfig "at0" "10.0.0.1" netmask "255.255.255.0"
ifconfig "at0" mtu 1500
route add -net "10.0.0.0" netmask "255.255.255.0" gw "10.0.0.1" dev "at0"
```

Into `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` I put the following:

```
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    authoritative;
    range 10.0.0.100 10.0.0.200;
    default-lease-time 3600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
    option routers 10.0.0.1;
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
    option domain-name “freeinternet.co.uk” 
}
```

Check that `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` has `INTERFACES=”at0”`

Start the DHCP Server:

```
/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart
```

Configure NAT and enable ip forwarding:

```
iptables --flush
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --delete-chain
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

At this stage I believe I should be able to connect a client to my access point and browse the web.

The **client** sees the access point, connects, gets an IP address from the server's DHCP (10.0.0.101) and then has the following routing table:

```
mark@laptop15:~/TT$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

However it cannot even ping the server (10.0.0.1) - no errors, we just don't get the pings back:

```
mark@laptop15:~/TT$ ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

And it stays like that forever.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was network-manager interfering.  Switched it off

```
service network-manager stop
```

and everything works fine.

I suspect there exists a less drastic solution than disabling it altogether, but it does what I need for now.